# ACT Light of Raspberry Pi is not ON continuously

Tags: boot, act, raspberry-pi-imager

I am having problem while working with Raspberry Pi Model B 4GB.

When I turn on the power of Raspberry Pi the power LED (red) turns on but the ACT LED (green/yellow) just flashes two times and suddenly disappears and Raspberry Pi do not boots.

Please help me out!

Comment: Have you read the boot sticky https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=58151#p1485558

Comment: The ACT light will only be on *continuously* in a model 2 with no SD card in (or an SD card it cannot read).  Otherwise it just blinks to indicate activity with the SD card, eg. at boot, usually quite vigorously for 5-20s, or, if there is some error with the content of the boot partition, it will blink endlessly in a regular pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The ACT (green) LED is configured in firmware to flash a "code" when there is a failure in boot process. The code has changed over time. I did a quick search for [**raspberry pi ACT LED codes**](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=raspberry+pi+ACT+LED+codes). The [first result](https://support.pishop.ca/article/33-raspberry-pi-act-led-error-patterns) seems current, but it indicates there is no code for 2 flashes.

You can also check the ["Official-but-hard-to-use" documentation for boot diagnostics](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#boot-diagnostics), and here again we find [no description for 2 flashes](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#led-warning-flash-codes).

As you've given us nothing else to go on, the following is offered purely as a ***GUESS***:

- Power supply < 5V
- No SD card?
- Improperly-formatted SD card